# Is there a IP-based login?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login

Starting from today I noticed that I get logged out from time to time at SE. It doesn't matter if I'm active or not. So normally I browse the web using [Tor](https://torproject.org/). Thatswhy "my" IP address changes every ten minutes and I assume that the login is connected with my current IP address. Is this true? If not what can be the reason for those logouts?

Comment: Hmm, since I wrote my question I never got logged out again. If this doesn't repeat in near future I'll close my question.

Answer (score 3):

Logins are not associated with IP addresses in any way. I expect something in the proxy layer is interfering with your cookies somehow.

Answer (score 2):

My ISP has dynamic IPs and my IP changes every few days (more if the router has spasms) but I'm not logged out.

They *might* do a whois on the IP to do an ISP or country-check but it's quite a lot of work for a relatively small problem.

It's more likely that your cookies are getting invalidated at some point or their servers just don't like you and keep dumping your session.

Answer (score 1):

I am logged in on my netbook via wireless and even I move around between different locations with totally different IPs and domains, I always stay logged in. It must have something to do with session management of your browser or the effect that tor has on it.